# Disable Client, Service and Protocols in the network adapter LAN Properties with Powershell on Windows7

Tags: windows, powershell

Is it possible to disable some `Client`, `Service` and `Protocols` items in `LAN Properties` of a network adapter on Windows7 using Powershell?

Comment: Give a example please

Comment: You're probably looking for [`nvspbind`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/191.hyper-v-tools-nvspbind.aspx).

Comment: Ansgar, that is what I needed. Thanks!